# Existence of points in a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g:\mathbf{R\rightarrow R}$ be a twice differentiable function.

a) Prove that if $a_1 < a_2$ and $g(a_1)=g(a_2)=0$, then there exists a point $m \in (a_1,a_2)$ such that $g'(m)=0$.

b) Prove that if $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$ and $g(a_1)=g(a_2)=g(a_3)=0$, then there exists a point $n \in (a_1,a_3)$ such that $g''(m)=0$.

I am just curious about how to prove this very rigorously. My intuition tells me that both parts are true, but I have a hard time putting it down in writing. Any general tips about how I can learn to do this better are also much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first one is well-known as the Rolle's Theorem. The second one is just the application of the first one: find some $m_{1},m_{2}$ such that $m_{1}\in(a_{1},a_{2})$, $m_{2}\in(a_{2},a_{3})$ and $g'(m_{1})=g'(m_{2})=0$, then use again Rolle's Theorem to find some $m_{3}\in(m_{1},m_{2})$ such that $g''(m_{3})=0$.

Comment: I don't think we have covered Rolle's theorem. Is there another, more simplistic way to do this perhaps?

Comment: That could be very challenging, then I would run the proof of Rolle's Theorem to get the result.

Comment: Maybe I should phrase it better - is there a way to show that this is a special case of the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes of course, because then $0=[g(a_{1})-g(a_{2})]/(a_{1}-a_{2})=g'(m)$ for some $m\in(a_{1},a_{2})$. However, in many literature, Mean Value Theorem is proved by Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Rolle's theorem is a particular case of the Mean Value Theorem, with the extra condition that $f(a) = f(b)$ for the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The first of these is called "Rolle's Theorem", and you only need once-differentiable; there are many proofs that you can google.

Once you read one of those, you may find it easy to do the second.

Comment: Would you be able to outline a proof for the second part?

Comment: I would, but I have chosen not to.